# Precompiled headers don't make me compile faster

Tags: c++, g++, precompiled-headers

I've just coded this little project to try out pre-compiled headers with g++ :

main.cpp :

```
#include "header.hpp"

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello world !" << std::endl;
}
```

header.hpp :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <stack>
#include <deque>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <unordered_map>
```

First, I compile the project normally :

```
$ time g++ main.cpp

real    0m0.738s
user    0m0.646s
sys     0m0.070s
```

Then I delete the output and I type `g++ header.hpp` so I can get the precompiled header file : `header.hpp.gch`

I compile the project again :

```
$ time g++ main.cpp

real    0m0.721s
user    0m0.626s
sys     0m0.072s
```

The compile time is exactly the same ! What's the use of pre-compiled headers if they don't improve the compilation speed !?

Did I make a mistake or what ?

Comment: _"Did I make a mistake"_ - Yes, you are compiling the same thing over and over again. What are you expecting `g++ header.hpp` to do to improve the thing? Please include the links or information you've read so it's easier to guide you.

Comment: I watched this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eSI4wctZUto&feature=share&si=ELPmzJkDCLju2KnD5oyZMQ and read this https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html

Comment: Do you have a `header.hpp.gch` where it needs to be?

Comment: Yes, in the same directory as my `header.hpp` file

Comment: Ok, then I need to think a bit. `0.7`-ish seconds to start up a program and execute it isn't so bad even if the program does nothing. Have you compared it to compiling a file with just `int main() {}` (no `#include`s at all)? How long does that take?

Comment: although not sure, I'd not surprise if compiler already optimize standard headers.

Comment: @TedLyngmo if I compile `int main() {}` it takes 0m0.107s

Comment: Ok, then it's probably so simple as, your precompiled header doesn't help in this situation. You can't compile templates into libs for example. Much of the standard library  consists of headers.

Comment: Maybe it’s that. Shame, I thought I could learn something useful. Lol

Comment: In this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X4pyOtawqjg&feature=share&si=ELPmzJkDCLju2KnD5oyZMQ a guy says pre-compiled headers are really efficient with Visual Studio. It could be for this reason I can’t get the same performance with g++.

Comment: Oh, you _can_ get a big boost in `g++` too - but you need to have something to measure it with. I suspect that the performance setup you've got going now is showing you how much it'd help in a big project